# What is the best practice to Jump out of closing bracket in Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

Its good when resharper inserts closing bracket automatically.
But assume condition that the method didn't have any parameter
in this situation it takes more time to jump out of the brackets is there a work around ?
now I use mouse to jump out from closing bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn this off by going to Resharper options/Editor and unchecking "Auto-insert pair brackets, parentheses, and quotes". I personally just use the right arrow key.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you haven't typed anywhere else, you should also be able to just type the closing brace and ReSharper should automagically skip over it as though it hadn't added it in the first place. (same thing works with closing quotes and semicolons, btw)

Comment: I found this to be the best method for me. That way you can still let the auto complete do it's job most of the time and if you need to add after the closing bracket, quote, semicolons etc you can as if ReSharper never added it! Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I have noticed that this doesn't always work though. Some times it just adds a second closing bracket and the original remains below your new one. :( Shame.

Comment: I think it probably depends on your settings, and (if I remember correctly), it's also somewhat touchy, especially about not using the arrow keys and such...